# Google Drive SDK JavaScript: upload and convert ppt(x) to presentation (Google Slides)

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, powerpoint

Based on the documentation this should be possible:
https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads#importing_to_google_docs_types_wzxhzdk8wzxhzdk9

I'm doing this from JavaScript, reading a ppt(x) file as a binary string and uploading to Google Drive v3 using the following settings:

mimeType: application/vnd.google-apps.presentation
contentType: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation

This results in a 500 error from the server and using contentType: application/octet-stream results in 400 error.

Any ideas/support would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to do this by sending the powerpoint binary string as base64 and I used convert=true as a request param.